# Sample AdMob IDs does not show ads

Tags: android, admob

I have created a minimal example.

Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        final InterstitialAd ad = new InterstitialAd(this);
        ad.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        ad.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        ad.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                ad.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cyberdynesoftware.interstitial">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cyberdynesoftware.interstitial"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Tested with a virtual device in Android Studio. The ad is not displayed.

And just to emphasize on this: The IDs shown are the sample IDs from https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start. The waiting period for newly created AD IDs does not apply here, as all answers I have found for the problem so far suggested.

This is the output from running the app:

```
02/08 17:41:02: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/dep/dependencies.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_1.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_2.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_0.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_4.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_5.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_3.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_7.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_6.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_8.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_9.apk /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/intermediates/instant-run-apk/debug/app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed in 1 s 942 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "cyberdynesoftware.interstitial/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 4708 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Verification of int android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.allocateRequestIndex(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) took 106.764ms
W/art: Verification of com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy, java.lang.String) took 539.431ms
W/art: Verification of java.lang.Object cyberdynesoftware.interstitial.MainActivity.access$super(cyberdynesoftware.interstitial.MainActivity, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) took 369.754ms
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite not found.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0
W/Ads: Data collection startup failed. No data will be collected.
    com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea.zzg(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb.zzgd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea$zzb.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    Failed to connect to measurement client.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:320 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0
    Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/Ads: #007 Could not call remote method. @28
    com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbg: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbe.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakm.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakn.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.instantiate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbe.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakm.zza(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakn.run(Unknown Source) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.instantiate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbe.zza(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakm.zza(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakn.run(Unknown Source) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:112)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:77)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:359)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeElements(DexPathList.java:323)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:263)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:520)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:553)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1866)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:766)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.<init>(ContextImpl.java:2038)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:1983)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5294)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/system/fake-libs:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/system/lib:/vendor/lib for namespace 0xae76f090
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/Chrome/lib/x86
D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/app/Chrome/lib/x86:/system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk!/lib/x86:/system/lib:/vendor/lib for namespace 0xae76f0d0
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 55.0.2883.91 (code 288309112)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 6 ms (timestamps 7357-7363)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(163)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9ed17940, tid 4708
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9ed11540: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9ed11540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9ed1bd10)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v14300000.14300000.0
I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/Ads: Google Play Service is out of date, the Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires updated Google Play Service.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa36ffe00, tid 4760
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae4069e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4069e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x852d0700)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
D/zzdl: File /data/user/0/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial/cache/1529567361524.dex not found. No need for deletion
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method double java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextDouble(double, double) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
    Before Android 4.1, method int java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextInt(int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
    Before Android 4.1, method long java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextLong(long, long) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15723(1928KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(804KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 5.982ms total 29.281ms
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4069e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x852d0700)
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is enabled.
E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver
E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x82f8a9c0, tid 4789
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x82f871e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x82f871e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x84aedf50)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x82f884a0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x82f884a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x84aedf50)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008a34
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008073
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ff
E/Ads: Error waiting for future.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbcl.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzatq.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzatq.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzats.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbu.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 4708
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 4708
```

**Update:** I've created a new Pixel 2 virtual device with Android 9, API level 28. The ad is still not shown. This is the output:

```
02/09 11:00:21: Launching app
$ adb push /Users/ingmar/projects/Interstitial/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial"
Success
APK installed in 5 s 319 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "cyberdynesoftware.interstitial/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 4587 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite not found.
W/re.interstitia: Unsupported class loader
W/re.interstitia: Long monitor contention with owner Thread-2 (4617) at int com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, boolean)(:55) waiters=0 in int com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, boolean) for 396ms
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:310
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 310
W/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version < 2, falling back to loadModule2
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0
W/Ads: Data collection startup failed. No data will be collected.
    com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea.zzg(Unknown Source:51)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb.zzgd(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea$zzb.run(Unknown Source:11)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    Failed to connect to measurement client.
W/re.interstitia: Unsupported class loader
W/re.interstitia: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/re.interstitia: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
W/re.interstitia: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v14300000.14300000.0
I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 66.0.3359.158 (code 336015817)
I/re.interstitia: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/re.interstitia: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/zzdl: File /data/user/0/cyberdynesoftware.interstitial/cache/1529567361524.dex not found. No need for deletion
W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
    The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
W/re.interstitia: Long monitor contention with owner pool-2-thread-12: (4646) at byte[] com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcw.zza(byte[], java.lang.String)(:57) waiters=5 in byte[] com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcw.zza(byte[], java.lang.String) for 110ms
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 1352-1354)
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd5844d40, tid 4660
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xec25ef40: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "66.0.3359.158", actual native library version number "66.0.3359.158"
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec25ef40: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe7870e00)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec25ef40: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe7870e00)
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

This time Google Play services are not out of date, but the ad is still not shown.

Comment: When you created your Ad Ids?

Comment: I did not create the Ad IDs, I'm using the sample ones.

Answer (score 2):

Updating your virtual device’s Google Play Service may help you.

Update

It seems the problem is different. I think creating a Google AdMob account and using your own AdMob app ID will surely fix the problem. You will use your own app ID but as unit ID you can still use test unit ID

Update 2

The problem may be your layout xml file or project-level build.gradle. Did you add following codes to your project-level build.gradle?

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
   google()
   jcenter()
     }
     }
```

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how. How can I update Google Play Services on a virtual device?

Comment: On virtual device Settings-Apps&notifications-Google Play Services-Advanced-App Details-Update

Comment: Under Settings->Apps->Google Play services there is an Advanced spacer, not clickable and no App Details or Update button. Tested on a Nexus 5X with Android 7.1.1, API level 25.

Comment: Using my own app ID did not make a difference. And I don't get why it should.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the same on physical Android device?

> Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470

I suspect this, so please change or update your play services version. Did you manually put the Play Services version in an integers.xml file or in the manifest file?

Let me know please to assist further, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a physical device available at the moment.

Comment: I put the play-services-ads dependency manually in the gradle build file, as instructed in the tutorial from Google.

Comment: But in your log, it shows that the Play Services version was outdated(10298470). So try to find that version in an integer.xml or update all google play services libraries to the newer version.

Comment: How can I update Google Play Services on a virtual device?

Comment: What is this integer.xml file?

Comment: The log saying that Google Play services are outdated is most likely the problem though. Thanks for pointing this out. I simply don't know what to do about it.